# Laravel - Looping thought $request and inserting data

Tags: jquery, laravel, foreach, insert, clone

I have a form to submit a job, with in the form there is a section where you can add extra info with a functionality to clone the fields.

I am having issues saving the record to my tasks table which is linked to the jobs table with the ID.

When the user clone the field I having trouble looping through the data and saving it in the data base.

I am cutting all the validation to save space. here is my store method in my JobController:

```
           public function store(Request $request)
                {
                    /*JOB*/
                    $job = new Job();
                    $job->title=$request->title;
                    $job->client_id=$request->client_id;
                    $job->user_id=$request->user_id;
                    $job-> number =$request->number;
                    $job->ponumber =$request->ponumber;
                    $job->status =$request->status;
                    $job->invoicestatus =$request->invoicestatus;
                    $job->save();
                    $lastInsertedId = $job->id;
                    /*TASK*/
                    $task = new Task();
                    $task->job_id = $lastInsertedId;
                    $task->description = $request->description;
                    $task->supplier_hs= $request->supplier_hs;
                    $task->quote_hs= $request->quote_hs;
                    $task->quote_hs_date= $request->quote_hs_date;
                    $task->quote_client= $request->quote_client;
                    $task->quote_client_date=   $request->quote_client_date;
                    $task->readytoinvoice= $request->readytoinvoice;
                    $task->invoiced= $request->invoiced;
                    $result = $task->getAttributes();
                    foreach($result as$key=>$t){
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach($result[$key] as $value){
                            echo"<pre>";
                            print_r($value);
                            echo"</pre>";
                            $i++;
                            echo "counter: " .$i;
                        }

                    }
                    //$task->save();


                    //return redirect('jobs')->with(array('feedback'=>'New Job created successfully','last_insert_id' => $job));


                }
```

This is the output I get from $result:

```
       Array
(
[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => job 1
        [1] => Job 2
        [2] => job 3
    )

[supplier_hs] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1000
        [1] => 200
        [2] => 3000
    )

[quote_hs] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1000
        [1] => 2000
        [2] => 300
    )

[quote_hs_date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2017-02-15 11:50:07
        [1] => 2017-02-01 00:00:00
        [2] => 2017-02-15 11:50:07
    )

[quote_client] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1000
        [1] => 2000
        [2] => 3000
    )

[quote_client_date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2017-02-15 11:50:07
        [1] => 2017-02-01 00:00:00
        [2] => 2017-02-15 11:50:07
    )

[readytoinvoice] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )

[invoiced] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )

)
```

this is what I would like to get as an result:

```
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => job 1
                    [supplier_hs]=> Job 2
                    [quote_hs] => job 3
                    [quote_hs_date] => 1000
                    [quote_client] => 2000
                    [quote_client_date] => 2017-02-15 11:50:07
                    [readytoinvoice] => 1
                    [invoiced] => 1
                ),
            [1] => Array
            (
                [description] => job 1
                [supplier_hs]=> Job 2
                [quote_hs] => job 3
                [quote_hs_date] => 1000
                [quote_client] => 2000
                [quote_client_date] => 2017-02-15 11:50:07
                [readytoinvoice] => 1
                [invoiced] => 1
            ),
            [2] => Array
            (
                [description] => job 1
                [supplier_hs]=> Job 2
                [quote_hs] => job 3
                [quote_hs_date] => 1000
                [quote_client] => 2000
                [quote_client_date] => 2017-02-15 11:50:07
                [readytoinvoice] => 1
                [invoiced] => 1
            )
        )
```

I've got it working this way. I am not really sure it is the best way to achieve this, but here's my code:

```
$tasks['tasks'] = array() ;
    foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        $i = 0;
        if(!is_null($key)){
            foreach($result as $value){
                if(!is_null($value)){
                    $index = array_keys($value);
                    foreach($index as $ind){
                        if($ind == $i){
                            $tasks['tasks'][$i]['job_id'] = $lastInsertedId;
                            $tasks['tasks'][$i][$key] = $result[$key][$i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What "trouble" are you having? Are you getting any errors? What is the current and expected result?

Comment: I have edited the question with result I get when I do a print_r on $result. I need to group the result by array keys. for example all the keys with 0 index in one array. @jedrzej.kurylo

Answer (score 0):

If it is what I understood that $result is originally an array of array (of each 'title' such as `quote_client` etc, then using this might be of help:

```
$finally = [];
$width = 0;
$keys = array_keys($result);
foreach ($keys as $kkk){
    foreach($result as $res_key => $res_value){                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        foreach($res_value as $key => $value)                                                                                                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            $finally[$width][$res_key] = $value;                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }
    $width ++;
}
```

> PS: Ofcourse this method has some nested loop so the efficiency is not guaranteed. However my thought is that there could be a method in laravel's collection that might be of help here.

Hope it helps :)